# How can I wrap header text in Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am writing some code to display some records in Grid view. I am using Firefox as my Default browser. I wish to wrap a header text. but Firefox is not supporting the wrap property. How can I achieve this?

Comment: No it has Space in between. The word is Monthly Limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a style sheet to the header template. In the style add white-space:normal. It will wrap the header text automatically

For eg, class name is mystyle in stylesheet:

```
.mystyle
{
  white-space:normal;
}
```

In the aspx page, include `Headerstyle-CssClass="myStyle"`.

Answer (score 4):

Use the Div tag to place the Header text. -- before that convert the BOUNDEDFIELD to the TEMPLATEFIELD

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UserID" SortExpression="UserID">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserID") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderTemplate>   <div STYLE="word-wrap: break-word">Your HEADER</div>
                           </HeaderTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField></asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Hi I am using it as a bound field. Is it possile to wrap the bound field?

Comment: thats what i have mentioned in the first line. You have to convert the bounded field to Template Field. so that you can have different templates like EditTemplate, ItemTemplate, HeaderTemplate.

Comment: if still want to stick to the bounded field try like the below.

<br>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="First Line<br />Second Line" DataField="ContactID"                HtmlEncode="False" />

Comment: Hi Friend that div property is also not supporting. what can i do?

Comment: kindly add the style to the div as shown in the answer - the answer have been changed.

Comment: This may work better if you add a width property to the div style attribute in the HeaderTemplate.  But, it also disables the ability to sort the grid by clicking the target column's heading text.

Answer (score 3):

Set attribute  `HeaderStyle-Wrap="true"` in `<asp:TemplateField>` tag

Please mark as answer if it helps.

Comment: Hi I already mentioned that Firefox is not Supporting that property. Sorry yaar

Answer (score -1):

`HeaderStyle-Wrap="true"` or `ItemStyle-Wrap="true"` cannot wrap header text. Only `HeaderStyle-Width = something`, say `"120px"`, then it will force the header text to wrap